# Lenovo B590 not Booting at all

Tags: boot, laptop, lenovo-laptop

My Lenovo B590 was working fine yesterday, today suddenly I can't make it boot up.

I have recorded a video that demonstrates the behaviour of the Laptop on Power On:
https://youtu.be/T9IcxsIgRcE

It remains in an endless loop of powering up for a sec, making some click-sound and turning off immediately. Longpress power button ends the loop.

AC cable is connected, battery is inserted.

Things I tried that didn't solve the issue:

- Power On only with AC cable (normally and with 20 sec long Power press)
- Power On only with battery (normally and with 20 sec long Power press)
- Removing both RAM and trying it with one each in each of both RAM slots

Probably an issue with the motherboard? Anything else I could try?

Comment: Some of the lenovo users also facing the same problem and they conformed with lenovo support that the mother board is fault. Once conform with service center.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting another monitor. I can't promise it will work, but at least you'll know if it's the graphics processor that's dead.

You should have a VGA and an HDMI plug on the left of your laptop.

If you connect it to another monitor and something shows, then it's your screen. If nothing appears, Your Graphic Processor might have shorted. It also could be the main Processor. Good luck !

Comment: Connecting an external Monitor did not change the behaviour. Is there a way to find out of it's the GPU or the CPU that is causing trouble? Could it also be the Mainboard?

Comment: There is probably no ways to know which one is dead, and yes, it could be your motherboard. I suggest you to bring your laptop into a "Computer repair" shop or something like that. I've had this problem with my HP, nothing was showing on the screen on boot. As I've studied in this domain, I asked one of my old teacher, he told me to put my motherboard into my Oven. There was more instructions than this, but that's basically what he told me to do. Go take a look on Google _Motherboard in oven_, you may want to give it a try.